# React (+ Typescript) component not rerendering upon updating Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a `LaunchItem` component which uses `React.Context` to get and set information to/from the local storage.

What I am trying to achieve is that, when the component updates the Context (and local storage), I want it to rerender with the new information, so that it then updates the state of a local button.

The problem is, although the Context seems to be updated as well as the contents of the local storage, the item is not rerendered. (when I refresh the page I can see the button has changed state, however, signifying that it is able to derive that information from the Context just fine.

I will now share some code and hopefully someone is able to understand what I might be missing, I thoroughly appreciate your help :)

### Context provider setup

```ts
type FavoritesContextType = {
  favorites: Favorites;
  updateFavorites: (category: StorageCategory, item: string) => void;
};

export const FavoritesContext = createContext<FavoritesContextType>(
  {} as FavoritesContextType
);

const FavoritesProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<Favorites>(
    getFromLocalStorage(SOME_CONSTANT)
  );

  const updateFavorites = (category: StorageCategory, item: string) => {
    updateLocalStorage(category, item);
    setFavorites(favorites);
  };

  return (
    <FavoritesContext.Provider value={{ favorites, updateFavorites }}>
      {children}
    </FavoritesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFavoritesContext = () => useContext(FavoritesContext);
```

### App.tsx

```ts
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <FavoritesProvider>
      {/* Some routing wrapper and a few routes each rendering a component */}
      <Route path="/launches" element={<Launches />} />
    </FavoritesProvider>
  )
```

### Launches.tsx

```ts
export const LaunchItem = ({ launch }: LaunchItemProps) => {
  const { favorites, updateFavorites } = useFavoritesContext();
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (favorites) {
      setIsFavorite(
        favorites.launches.includes(launch.flight_number.toString())
      );
    }
  }, [favorites]);

  return (
    {/* The rest of the component, irrelevant */}
    <FavoriteButton
      isFavorite={isFavorite}
      updateFavorites={() => {
        updateFavorites(
          StorageCategory.Launches,
          launch.flight_number.toString()
          );
       }}
   />
  )
```

### FavoriteButton.tsx

```ts
export const FavoriteButton = ({
  isFavorite,
  updateFavorites,
}: FavoriteButtonProps) => {
  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateFavorites();
  };

  return (
    // Using Link vs a Button to be able to preventDefault of parent Link
    <Link
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
    {/* The rest of the component, irrelevant */}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though in your `updateFavorites` function you're calling `setFavorites` and passing in the existing `favorites` value. Try instead writing your `updateFavorites` function as:

```
  const updateFavorites = (category: StorageCategory, item: string) => {
    updateLocalStorage(category, item);
    setFavorites(getFromLocalStorage(SOME_CONSTANT));
  };
```

There are other ways you could determine what value to pass to `setFavorites` but I reused your `getFromLocalStorage` function as I'm not sure how you're determining that state value.

By doing it this way you'll ensure that the value you're setting in `setFavorites` isn't the same as the existing `favorites` value and thus you'll trigger a re-render.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works as intended. :) I was incorrectly assuming that the `favorites` state of the Provider would be updated when calling the `updateFavorites` callback. But that's not how it works, instead the `favorites`state is only updates when using the `setFavorites` setter, which makes total sense to get from the newly updated local storage. Thanks again!